# Can I reshape a non-contiguous view in rust-ndarray?

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

This program compiles, but panics at run time with the message below. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a4b41cec2eada29312a0c9aceeda3e2c))

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let a = Array2::<i32>::zeros([100, 10]);
    let b = a.slice(s![5..15, ..8]);
    let c = b.into_shape((10, 2, 4)).expect("should work");
    dbg!(c);
}
```

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'should work: ShapeError/IncompatibleLayout: incompatible memory layout', src/main.rs:6:38
```

Reshaping fails because the view `b` is not contiguous.

But this reshape is just splitting one axis in two, which can always be done safely. Analogous code works fine in NumPy:

```py
a = np.arange(1000).reshape((100, 10))
b = a[5:15, :8]
c = b.reshape((10, 2, 4))

# array([[[ 50,  51,  52,  53],
#         [ 54,  55,  56,  57]],
#
#        [[ 60,  61,  62,  63],
#         [ 64,  65,  66,  67]], ...])
```

How can I do that in Rust?

Comment: You can create a contiguous version of b: `let b_contiguous = b.to_owned().to_shared();`

Comment: Is it possible that changing the major order of the array would fix this? Is it in column-major when it should be row-major or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as contiguous using the as_standard_layout function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).